# How to create HttpResponseMessage in a non-APIController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I have a service layer called **GatewayService** which calls another **WebApi** to get the product information and manipulate the **Inventory** in the response and return the same response to the caller.

Here is the code I have. The problem that I have is, I can't use **Request.CreateResponse(...)** which will give me a compilation error because **GatewayService** does not inherit **ApiController**.

Is there a way to update the response and return as HttpResponseMessage?

```
public class GatewayService
{
    // Code Removed for bravity

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(SingleProductSearcRequest request)
    {
        var response = productServiceWebApi.Get(request); // Returns HttpResponseMessage

        var p = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>().Result;

        p["Inventory"] = "Not Available";

        return Request.CreateResponse(p); // COMPILER ERROR!!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request.CreateResponse()` is just an extension method for `HttpRequest`. You can manually construct an `HttpResponseMessage` as well as give it content by doing something like:

```
var p = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>().Result;

HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
message.Content = new ObjectContent(p);
```

You can transfer headers and other information over as well, if necessary. Depending on the need, there's also `StringContent`, etc.